# I cannot install Polybar on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

I have been trying to install Polybar for a long time now. I managed to find two options that I could utilise.

**1. Try and build the program by source (using instructions from the github).**

I try to do all this, until I hit a brick wall, called cmake .. , which returns this...

```
-- No build type specified; using RelWithDebInfo
-- Using supported compiler GNU-5.4.0
-- Checking for module 'xcb-xkb'
--   No package 'xcb-xkb' found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:367     (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:532     (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  cmake/common/utils.cmake:235 (pkg_check_modules)
  cmake/03-libs.cmake:17 (querylib)
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/textman/polybar/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/textman/polybar/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I look up xcb-xkb to download it, and after some research, I realise that I have no idea how to download that package. I found this website called xcb.freedesktop (.org), but I couldn't find a xcb-xkb.

**2. Just install it from GetDeb: http://www.getdeb.net/app/Polybar**

I hit the big install button, after I add GetDeb as a repository, and it asks me whether I want to install it. I confirm, and then it returns this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

polybar: Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0) but 1:6.0.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
         Depends: libiw30 (>= 30~pre1) but 30~pre9-8ubuntu1 is to be installed
         Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 6) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4 is to be installed
         Depends: libxcb-xrm0 (>= 0.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
```

Apparently I need various versions of Ubuntu to install these dependencies, apart from libxcb-xrm0 which apparently is just not going to be installed.

The website itself says that there is a version for Xenial, and I even tried getting the .deb packages from UbuntuUpdates, but whenever I click the Install button, nothing happens.

I'm a bit of a newbie, I've had Ubuntu for a week now, and even though I've been working and learning about it a lot, I still encounter problems like dependencies and the whole xcb thing.

Been driving me so mad that I created a whole askubuntu account for it...

Also, I couldn't post all the links to all the websites cause I don't have any reputation apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is not a .deb available for you I would compile from source.

To compile from source you need to install the dependencies. Not just the packages, but the headers in the -dev packages.

Google search the name of the package...

https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+dependencies+xcb-xkb&oq=ubuntu+dependencies+xcb-xkb

and you can see it is in the libxcb-xkb-dev so

```
sudo apt-get install libxcb-xkb-dev
```

and on for each dependency.

See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo It is a long page but will walk you through what you need to know to compile.

Comment: I didn't know about what link, and the google trick I have never tried before, I always just searched the dependency name beforehand. This worked perfectly, after doing this with all dependencies it worked brilliantly. Thank you.